# How to tell mongoose to automatically increase a stored value after a specific amount of time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Let's say I a student model like this:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const StudentSchema = new Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        maxLength: 60,
        minLength: 3,
    },
    studentID: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      maxLength: 60,
      minLength: 3,
    },
    semester: {
      type: Number,
      min: 1,
      max: 15,
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('StudentModel', StudentSchema);
```

How can I tell mongoose to automatically increase the **semester** by **one** each 6 months in an Express app?

Comment: Can you not calculate the correct semester given the current date and the start date of the student? The only way to do it automatically would be to create a background job that runs every 6 month and checks the db and then updates the semester.

Comment: @SebastianAmmon I guess I could, didn't think of that. but I'm still not sure how to implement it. The student has to register and enter their current semester. How would their semester change in the DB after 6 months? edit: I see, thank you for your answer. I'll do my research on that.

Comment: Yes, and then whenever you're interested in knowing what semester they are currently in, then you would calculate how many months have passed. You could look into something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron for running scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a example maybe could help. add this property.

```
semester_next_time: {
      type: Date,
    }

StudentSchema.pre('find', function() {
   // if semester_next_time is   less than now  do stuff and update next time semester
});
```

Comment: This makes a ton of sense! Thanks for your response!

Comment: @ArminE look at this for more details : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining